# Why can't a field itself have getters/setters like properties do?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm a C# beginner, so easy explanations are greatly appreciated.
I was learning about properties, and got this question: properties give custom access logic to fields, but why can't the field itself contain its getter/setter? In other words, is there a reason why we can't get rid of Example and write custom get/setters under example(field)?

I could not find other posts that answer my question.

```
class MyClass
{
   private int example = 5;
   public int Example
       {
            get;
            private set;
       }
   // here, this Example property only acts as a gateway for example.
   // why is it not possible for the field 'example' to contain the 
   // get/set?
}
```

Comment: You can use auto-properties `public int Example { get; set; }`. No backing field required. If that's what you're asking. Btw, `int example` should be `private`, if it acts as the backing field for `Example`.

Comment: @Jimi: Well, there *is* a backing field - just not one in the source code.

Comment: you can always change field value by using dot operator access, you dont need to define additional property if thats what you are asking new class().fieldname=5 will also work, it can even be left with no assingment till use require.

Comment: @Alok: I would *strongly* recommend against "just expose public fields until it turns out we need a property". That's a backwardly incompatible change, and in my view it violates encapsulation. I view a field as an implementation detail of how information is *stored*, whereas the property is how you want the information to be *exposed*.

Comment: @JonSkeet i know but i think OP wants to know if its possible or not, functionality and encapsulation is altogether different from what he is asking

Comment: @Alok: I think we're interpreting the question differently, but your comment of "it can even be left with no assingment till use require" definitely sounded more like a recommendation of how to evolve a project rather than what's *feasible*.

Comment: @JonSkeet it was based on the same understanding, also i cant write very lenghty definitions or excerpts in comment, so once the discussion goes to something fruitful a nice answer with details of how & what with do's and dont's can be compiled.

Comment: Fields are just storage and don't have any logic directly associated with them.  Properties basically exist to give you the ability to include logic around getting and setting some value on a class which may or may not involve a field.

Comment: Btw2, as of C#6, you can also assign a value directly: `public int Example { get; set; } = 5` -- @Jon Skeet Well, yes, of course. I didn't think the OP needed a description of what the compiler is doing behind the curtain when an auto-property is used. But, yes, the backing fields are still there, sugar-coated.

Comment: The question simply makes no sense: __Once you add get/setter to a variable it becomes a property__. There is not 'explanation' needed, really. - Beginners often see problems where there are none at all..

Comment: _"why can't the field itself contain its getter/setter?"_ -- because, as @TaW has pointed out, if it did have those things, then it would be a property, not a field. A field is a variable, which is very different from a property, which is a pair of methods with specific semantics. The field is like other variables, which you might find as parameters for a method, or local variables in a method. Do you want those things to also have getters and setters? Do you see why they shouldn't?

Comment: @JonSkeet In what context do you see public fields converting to properties being backwards incompatible? Unless your project is advanced enough to use DLLs, or you are a library developer, (a very small group) I don't see why it isn't acceptable.

Comment: @NetMage: They're binary incompatible to start with, and you can't pass properties by reference.

Comment: (There's more than that, but those are the two that came to mind immediately.)

Comment: @TaW A property cannot hold data for itself, right(to my knowledge)? Then isn't it impossible to just add get/setters to a field that holds data and make it a property?

Comment: @Jimi public int Example { get; set; } = 5 is this considered a field or a property?

Comment: It has a getter and a setter: it can only be a Property. In this case, an initial value (you can consider it a *default* value) has been assigned (`C# 6+`). Yes, a Property holds a value, but it can also perform an *action* when the Getter or the Setter methods are invoked. In this case, you usually add a backing field (there's more to it, though). You can see Jon Skeet's blog about this: [C# 6 in action](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/12/08/c-6-in-action/). And, of course, [the C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/).

Comment: _A property cannot hold data for itself, right(to my knowledge)?_ Wrong. It will hold data in its (possibly hidden) field..

Answer (score -1):

Property is an interface to Class, and not always is about storing data, you can always make the variable public member and will work perfectly like property, but the property has its own main job to work as an interface for that value with other classes.
While in many cases the property just works as public parameters, it is not always meant to be used in that way.